# Executing external programs in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am executing a few external programs from a Perl script and want to automatically handle prompts from that program. I know what the prompts are, they are not error conditions, and I want the script to handle them and not the user.

What's best practice for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My first stop would be the [`Expect` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect/). I'm not sure if I'd need a second stop after that.